# Access OpenVPN Client from public IP

Tags: server, openvpn

Hi i just setup OpenVPN Server with Ubuntu Server to play PS4 over Internet (With Remote Play) since my ISP doesn't give me a public ip so i create a OpenVPN in Google Cloud. And i've successfully connect my ps4 over internet with my android. But when i connect to to PS4, i must connect my PS4 with openvpn enabled (with openwrt) and my android too. to connect i must enter openvpn ip (10.8.0.2) not my Google Cloud IP (ex. 34.xx.xx.xx).

I just wanna ask how to access my OpenWRT with public IP of my Google Cloud instead connect between client and enter IP of OpenVPN (10.8.0.2)

This is my diagram

**My GoogleCloud (34.80.100.4)**   ==>  **OpenVPN (10.8.0.1)**   ==>  **OpenWRT (10.8.0.2)**  ==> **PS4 (192.168.1.239)**

My PS4 IP is local because connected to Router OpenWRT.

Can i just enter 34.80.100.4 to reach OpenWRT 10.8.0.2??

Thanks Before

Comment: How does this relate to Ubuntu?

Comment: Oh my bad, i use ubuntu server

Comment: please remember that if you're using OpenVPN with certs, you need one cert for each device, otherwise you won't be able to connect from both devices at the same time

Comment: Can I just using IP public to access my device in OpenVPN without client?